# How to find two unknown values in a dataframe? Finding Values Solver

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy, cvxpy

my problem is a bit complicated I haven't been able to solve it for months,

First I have a dataframe in this form, with Pr more than 500 lines (+ P300)

```
Product A       B       C       D       TF
P1      11.0    NaN     NaN     NaN     T1
P2      NaN     14.0    NaN     NaN     T2
P3      7.0     NaN     13.0    NaN     T3
P4      7.5     NaN     NaN     14.0    T4
P5      NaN     12.0    NaN     13.5    T5
P6      14.4    NaN     17.0    20.0    T6
P7      NaN     NaN     NaN     14.0    T7
```

I want to get the values of TF and A, B, C, D to minimize the difference, to better explain you I will give you examples:

I have the rule that says:

```
T1 * (1-A) = 11

T2 * (1-B) = 12

T3 * (1-A) = 7
T3 * (1-C) = 13

T6 * (1-A) = 14.4
T6 * (1-C) = 17
T6 * (1-D) = 20
```

How I could find all the T, and at the same time A, B, C, D so that my grid is in an optimized way , enter code here

thank you so much

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried, but I really don't understand your question.. Can you give a bit more context? What is `T1`, `T2`, ... ? Strings? Numbers? What do you mean with `T1 * (1-A) = 11`? `A` is 11.0, so `1-11=-10`?

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan I tried using cvxpy (https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/intro/index.html) but I have not found the comments make when I values my T, I get to have A, B, C, D

Comment: @GijsWobben Thank you for you trying.
To better explain, T1 * (1-A) = 11, where T1 and A are integers, so the solution can be 12 and A = 0.08 because 12 * (1-0.08) =10.92 and this is n ' is not far from 11